# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'; 'xyz' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing issues in relative imports in python. Below is my python3 project structure.

```
    .
├── production
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── database_connection.py
│   ├── prod-404-error-status-only.py
│   └── search_filter_criteria.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── send_email_script.py
    └── utils.py
```

The error i am getting is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "production/search_filter_criteria.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils.utils import get_date_string, read_txt, read_xml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Try tried in many different ways. Added **init**.py files to each module, still facing the issue.

Comment: just do `from database_connection import DatabaseOperations` No need to add `production` Because file `search_filter_criteria.py` is in same folder as `database_connection.py`

Comment: Now i am getting new error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "production/search_filter_criteria.py", line 11, in <module>
    from utils.utils import get_date_string, read_txt, read_xml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Comment: Check the error.

Comment: if `xyz` is your package where `__init__.py`, `production` & `utils` resides, you need to either use absolute or relative path in the scripts inside `production` folder that imports any in `utils`. so `from xyz.utils.utils` instead of `from utils.utils`

Comment: @cryptonome root directory is not python package. Not working

Answer (score 0):

Since, the files are in different folders, You would need to append path before `from utils.utils import get_date_string, read_txt, read_xml` line.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/root/directory/of/project')
```